# By which rule(s), is the Rust compiler ensuring that the lock is released?

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand the behaviour of Rust's Mutex, using small snippets. I have a reasonable idea about RAII, the role that `MutexGuard` plays and I am aware the fact that `lock()` is blocking call.

The following code ( Snippet **1** ) works:

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let a_mutex = Mutex::new(5);
    let v = a_mutex.lock().unwrap().to_string();

    // An attempt to acquire the lock again.
    let w = a_mutex.try_lock().unwrap();
}
```

But this code ( Snippet **2** ), doesn't work!

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let a_mutex = Mutex::new(5);
    let v = a_mutex.lock().unwrap();

    // An attempt to acquire the lock again.
    let w = a_mutex.try_lock().unwrap();
}
```

The output, predictably tells me that the attempt to acquire the lock again, will not succeed ( *WouldBlock*; from my Unix/C programming days, I have a fair idea of what an `EWOULDBLOCK` indicates ).

```bash
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.29s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: "WouldBlock"', src/main.rs:19:32
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

This ( Snippet **3** ) tells us - unsurprisingly - that the lock is not released by the time, we are trying to acquire it again:

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let a_mutex = Mutex::new(5);

    let v = a_mutex.lock().unwrap();
    println!("v = {:?}", v.to_string());
    
    let w = a_mutex.try_lock().unwrap();
}
```

The output says it all:

```bash
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.60s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: "WouldBlock"', src/main.rs:19:32
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

v = "5"
```

I understand that the behaviour has to do with scoping rules, temporaries and expressions.

May be even with *{ Place | Value } Contexts* too, but I am unsure about this part.

But I am failing to explain to myself, which rule(s) determine(s) that difference between the behavior of Snippets 1/2/3. In particular:

```rust
 let v = a_mutex.lock().unwrap().to_string();
```

and

```rust
 let v = a_mutex.lock().unwrap();
```

Both are expressions, but in the first case the `MutexGuard` is released. What am I missing?

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75364568/is-this-because-the-mutex-was-not-released), and [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#temporaries), but these failed to make me see the light.

Looking forward to a nudge or two, that makes my understanding clearer.

TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first snippet, the lock guard is a temporary and dropped at the end of the statement, while in the second and third snippets it is a normal variabled and dropped at the end of the scope.

When you do `let v = a_mutex.lock().unwrap();`, you assign the [`MutexGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html) to a variable. As all variables, it is dropped at the end of the scope, after the `try_lock()`.

However, when you call `to_string()` on it, the lock is stored nowhere - only the string is stored in a variable. As such, the lock is a temporary. Sometimes, when appearing in a `let` statement, temporaries are extended until the end of the scope, but when this is a method call (`temporary.method()`) they are not and they are dropped at the end of the statement, before the `try_lock()` call.

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks for a quick clarification. Could you please point me to the section in the rust-book that elaborates this: > " .. when this is a method call (temporary.method()) they are not and they are dropped at the end of the statement,... "

Comment: @Nirmalya [Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#extending-based-on-expressions) the reference lists all extended expressions, method calls is not within them.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of the topic of 'extending expressions' . I will have to study that further. Thanks for pushing me towards that.

Comment: I had  forgotten to accept the answer. Apologies.

Answer (score 3):

This might be help to clarify Chayim Friedman' answer

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let a_mutex = Mutex::new(5);

    {
        let v = a_mutex.lock().unwrap();
    }
    // v is droped at this moment

    // An attempt to acquire the lock again.
    let w = a_mutex.try_lock().unwrap();
}
```

When you do as this

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let a_mutex = Mutex::new(5);
    let v = a_mutex.lock().unwrap();

    // An attempt to acquire the lock again.
    // v is still valid and you can't lock it again.
    let w = a_mutex.try_lock().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. However, this was my exact question. That unseen pair of braces is put by the compiler in the snippet 1 but not in snippet 2. Obviously, a specific scoping rule was being applied. I wanted to know, which was that.

Comment: @Nirmalya The Rust team has documented this topic very well. Please refer to  [Variable Scope](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#variable-scope) and [Scoping rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope.html).